# Multiple Select controll inside CollectionView with common filtered content

Tags: ember.js

Is there any possibility to choose multiple objects from one common list?

My case is like this:

- I have list of many (let's say 100) persons
- I need to choose only few of them
- Every person have to be choosen at most once (selected person should not be in content list of Select control)

Visual example:

Person array (Select's **CONTENT**):

```js
App.personsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content:["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person5"]
})
```

We have 2 buttons to add and remove rows:

**(+)** button perform '*add*' action that call **person.createRecord** to add another item to ItemView inside CollectionView

**(x)** button perform '*remove*' action that call **person.deleteRecord** for delete record

This is what we see first:

- (+)(x)

**1st action - CLICK ADD**

So after performing 'click' action we have list like this:

- Person1 *<- this is actualy DropdownList (Select control)*
- (+)(x)

Table of content for all Select's now is:

["Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person5"]

**2nd action - CLICK ADD**

- Person1
- Person2
- (+)(x)

Table of content for Select:

["Person3", "Person4", "Person5"]

**3rd action - SELECT**

Now we change Person2 to Person5

- Person1
- Person5
- (+)(x)

Table of content:

["Person2", "Person3", "Person4"]

**4th action - CLICK REMOVE**

Now we remove Person1 from list

- Person5
- (+)(x)

Table of content:

["Person1:, "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"]

As You can see table content is changing with selected context.

**Problems:**

Select View in template have contentBinding which i want to bind with my *content* table, but if I remove already selected item, then it won't show in html select-option attribute.
I tried to use selectionBinding but it seems not working in that way.

As far as I know we should:

- use 2 lists:

  - selectedPersons
  - notSelectedPersons
- use **CollectionView** with **ItemView** to track each Select element individualy
- feed each {{view Select **contentBinding** }} with **notSelectedPersons**
- feed each {{view Select **selectionBinding** }} with **selectedPersons**

Is there any posibility in ember.js to achieve result similar to this above?